# Calculate a mathematical operation between two records with a custom function

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am stuck on an Access Function.

I have the following query:
[image]

```
EWMA=(SessionLoad Actual record *(2/(28+1))+((1-(2/(28+1)))*EWMA from the previous record)
```

I would have to get the data this way:

Query I want to do:
[image]

Comment: Please change your question title. This has nothing to do with `Maths` :)

Answer (score 0):

Getting value from previous record requires subquery.

```
SELECT Sessions.*, (SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.SessionLoad
    FROM Sessions AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.ID<Sessions.ID ORDER BY ID Desc) AS PrevLoad
FROM Sessions;
```

However, calculation dependent on calculation in previous record is not practical in Access query.

I tested your formula in Excel and it does not produce the results you show.